# Is it possible to "unset" an echo?

Tags: php

simple question >>

i'm now learning php and i get some things in mind wich is >>>

how it's can be done ! ... wich my question is :

is the echo have or i can do unset or something that if (if statement got true ) remove the echo or unset echo or something ?

like this ... :

```
$name = belal ;

echo "$name";

if ($name == belal ) {

  "unset echo (or) "remove echo "


 }
```

Note : " (or) i not mean by it that i execute as a code it's word so i can explaining my question "

this is not a question that i need it really for build something

it's just a "query" in my mind specially

i'm go to learning php 100% so i want everything in my mind ask to it Decidedly

so thanks

Comment: of course i know how to set a variable again ... but a just asking remove echo .... thanks

Comment: See the duplicate question/answer, but *don't use this approach* even if it can be used. Simply, only echo/write output when you *should*.

Comment: yes this link is reset a variable witch is easy and known but just i'm asking if echo can removed with if statment ... thanks

Comment: so like im said it's a just small qustion that i get out of learning with out missed word in php hhh .. thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Do the check before the echo or if this is for a website echo the content in a `<span>` tag and use CSS to hide it.

Checking before the echo:

```
$name = "foo";
if( $name == "foo" ){
    echo $name;
}
```

Changing the CSS:

```
$name = "foo";
echo '<span class="hidey">'.$name.'</span>';
$name = "bar";
if( $name != "foo"){
    echo "<style>.hidey{ display: none;</style>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For output control I can only think of [Output Control Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) in the PHP documentation.

Try to look into the example of [ob_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php).

Hope this helps.